# Rotation With Animation in GPUImage

Tags: ios, animation, filter, rotation, gpuimage

I Am using GPUImage.
I Want to Rotate (With 90, 180, 270, 360 degree) Image With Animation using GPUImageFilter.

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Just Check What i did to do For Rotation
int tag - is defined in .h file

```
-(IBAction)btnRotate_Clicked:(id)sender  
{  
[self hideFilterView];
[self hideFontView];
[self hideEnhanceView];

if (tag == 0)
{
    staticPictureOriginalOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight;
    tag = 1;
}
else if (tag == 1)
{
    staticPictureOriginalOrientation = UIImageOrientationDown;
    tag = 2;
}
else if (tag == 2)
{
    staticPictureOriginalOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeft;
    tag = 3;
}
else
{
    staticPictureOriginalOrientation = UIImageOrientationUp;
    tag = 0;
}

UIImageOrientation orientation = staticPictureOriginalOrientation;
switch(orientation){
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        [self.MimageView setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill];
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        [self.MimageView setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio];
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        [self.MimageView setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatio];
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        [self.MimageView setFillMode:kGPUImageFillModePreserveAspectRatioAndFill];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
[self prepareStaticFilter];
}

 -(void) prepareStaticFilter
 {
isImageProcessed = TRUE;
[staticPicture addTarget:filter];

if (hasBlur)
{
    [filter addTarget:blurFilter];
    [blurFilter addTarget:self.MimageView];
}
else
{
    [filter addTarget:self.MimageView];
}

GPUImageRotationMode imageViewRotationMode = kGPUImageNoRotation;
switch (staticPictureOriginalOrientation)
{
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        imageViewRotationMode = kGPUImageRotateLeft;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        imageViewRotationMode = kGPUImageRotateRight;
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        imageViewRotationMode = kGPUImageRotate180;
        break;
    default:
        imageViewRotationMode = kGPUImageNoRotation;
        break;
}
[filter setInputRotation:imageViewRotationMode atIndex:0];
[staticPicture processImage];
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have done so far?

Comment: Thanks for reply Adam. now please check it again this link. i edited it, now it show what i did to rotate image. this code rorated image properly, but without animation. Please Help. Thanks again & advance too.